# How can I move an integer number into a XMM register with Cheat Engine?

Tags: disassembly, register, cheat-engine

First off, I need to clear out that I'm a total noob on this, and I have tried reading and understanding documentation about this assembly stuff on the internet, but almost all I found, was meant for advanced people who knew about this.

So, what I have tried so far, is something like "movaps XMM6, 9999999" (from the original instruction "movaps XMM6,XMM1"), but it won't work when I try to create a Cheat Engine Table, it tells me

> Error in line 12 (movaps XMM6, 9999999): This instruction can't be compiled.

I'm sorry if I'm not specific enough, I would appreciate someone to further explain me how registers like these work, and how to exchange values between those and maybe other variables?
*I did read the thread about sending a integer into an XMM using another register, **but I didn't catch a thing out of that**, so I wrote this thread.* I'm looking forward to learning about this...

Answer (score 2):

By its definition, `movaps` instruction can't get immediate value. It can only get another register or memory location. You can see it in its [documentation](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_180.html).

> MOVAPS xmm1, xmm2/m128    Move packed single-precision floating-point values from xmm2/m128 to xmm1.

> MOVAPS xmm2/m128, xmm1    Move packed single-precision floating-point values from xmm1 to xmm2/m128.

You can see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654099/how-to-move-128-bit-immediates-to-xmm-registers) for different solutions to your problem.